# Ordering / Organizing Highest to Lowest string [][] after each pass

Tags: java, arrays, swing, multidimensional-array, organization

I have a JFrame and a JPanel that optains a chart. The chart has 10 vertical spots for the players (1 extra for the menu) and 3 horizontal spots for "#","Name","Score".
At each turn, the player enters his name, while his score is saved.
I want to print his/her name with his/her score at each round. So if 6 games are played, there will be 6 names and their scores alongside them. All must be ordered from highest to lowest scores.

The Variables used are:

```
private int score;
private String[] playerscore = {"#","Name", "Score"};
private String[][] singleplay = {{"#","Name","Score"},{"1","----------","--"},{"2","----------","--"},{"3","----------","--"},{"4","----------","--"},{"5","----------","--"},{"6","----------","--"},{"7","----------","--"},{"8","----------","--"},{"9","----------","--"},{"10","----------","--"}};
```

I believe that there must be two arrays for name and string, which will be used to get all the data from "singleplay" and be organize. I've used:

```
int [] ascore = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
String [] aname = {"","","","","","","","","",""};
```

I need help making table organize, while also adding the 'chart is full' condition. For example: "if the score is less than player number 10 score, do nothing.
I kind of have an idea that the content at position x should be saved in the ascore and aname. I've tried to save the content to organize later by doing:

```
ascore [0] = Integer.parseInt(singleplay[1][2]);
aname [0] = singleplay[1][1];
```

And after the organization of the 'ascore' and 'aname', I will print it by using:

```
singleplay[x][2] = Integer.toString(ascore[y]);
singleplay[x][1] = aname [y];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure of what it is you're trying to do exactly, but from what I gather, I have a few suggestions: 1) organize the structure of the data independent of Swing. It looks like you're trying to use parallel arrays when you should instead be using custom classes to hold data that needs to stay together. 2) Consider using a database to hold the data. 3) If you need to display and interact with tabular data, consider using a JTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a name and score for each record. You can create class Record:

```
class Record {
  private String name;      
  private int score;

  public Record(String name, int score){
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  public int getScore(){
    return score;
  }
}
```

Then you could keep those records in a list, for example ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();
records.add(new Record("Joe", 5));
records.add(new Record("Kathy", 7));
```

Then you could sort this list

```
Collections.sort(records, new GameRecordsComparator());
```

where GameRecordComparator is:

```
class GameRecordComparator implements Comparable<Record> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Record r1, Record r2) {
    return r1.getScore() - r2.getScore();
  }
}
```

You want to have max 10 records, so before inserting you may check list size

```
if (records.size()<10){
  records.add(...); // add your newly created record

} else if (records.get(9).getScore()<score) {
  // elements in a list are 0-based, 9 means 10th element
  // score is a score of a new element, which user wants to enter

  records.remove(9);
  records.add(...); // add your newly created record
  Collections.sort(records, new GameRecordsComparator());
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to the way I asked on the question? I only want to use one public void, I have my scores and names taken but how do I display them all in order? plus the full spots condition. Only show me the for loops for organizing using my variables and display. Regards